# What is the purpose of the op-amps connected back to back in a thermocouple signal conditioner?

Tags: analog, signal, thermocouple

I am trying to design a thermocouple signal conditioner. I came across this structure on the Analog Devices LTC2057 typical application page.

Why was such a connection made instead of using a single op-amp as a differential amplifier? What is the purpose of the op-amps connected back to back in a thermocouple signal conditioner?

(LTC2057 High Voltage, Low Noise Zero-Drift Operational Amplifier)

[image]
Source: [LTC 2057 datasheet, page 26](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/2057f.pdf)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why was such a connection made instead of using a single opamp as a differential amplifier?

Discrete differential amplifier configurations are inherently more noisy, have worse CMRR, and have higher DC errors, than non-differential amplifiers. If you can set up an op-amp to do the amplification without taking the difference, and then follow it by a subtractor, that often yields better results. And that's what was done here.

In the circuit you refer to, LTC2057 is a regular inverting 250x amplifier, with the input and output referenced to the (-) thermocouple terminal instead of ground.

LT1991A has differential inputs, and takes the difference between the LTC2057 output and the (-) thermocouple terminal. The difference is then amplified.

If a circuit is easily amenable to *not* using a differential amplifier as the first stage, then it's worth considering not using the differential first-stage.

The so-called "standard" differential amplifier connection using 1, 2 or 3 discrete op-amps is hard to get to perform well. Yes, it is commonly shown in textbooks and teaching materials, but that doesn't mean it should be used without a proper error analysis. The error analysis usually shows that even a basic integrated instrumentation amplifier beats the pants off a textbook discrete solution in terms of DC errors and CMRR.

Yes, there are situations where differential first-stage amplification yields best results - it may be in a discrete form, or using an integrated instrumentation or differential input amplifier. As always: one has to understand the performance of various architectures, and choose one that fits the bill best for the level of performance needed.

Today there's plenty of cheap CMOS instrumentation amplifiers that have "jellybean" prices and those can be considered general purpose parts anytime you want to take DC or AC differences and amplify them. That was not the case 20 years ago. So, today, jellybean in-amps are worth using if the performance is sufficient, since they are easy to apply.

Analog CMOS facilitates in-amp architectures that perform very well given how cheap they are to manufacture, and don't even require tight resistor matching. For example, the input differential voltage can be converted to a current, and then that current goes through a transimpedance stage that provides voltage amplification. That can work from quite low voltages that would not have been feasible in bipolar technology without costing a whole lot and being finicky to apply. The "pinnacle" of low voltage bipolar is the LM10 op-amp - a rather complex part for being "just an op amp with a voltage reference".

Comment: Does this caveat also apply to a fully differential amplifier followed by a subtractor?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Fully differential amplifiers are usually used where they are really needed, so the caveat is sort of preempted - anything else will perform worse. Typically that would be in high bandwidth scenarios. For things "close to DC" it's different, and a fully differential amp may be less accurate but also less noisy than an instrumentation amp, whereas a "single op-amp" will be best. It also is worth evaluating it, since I work with instrumentation from DC up to audio frequencies, so it's a rather specific area.

Comment: Thanks for answer "Discrete differential amplifier configurations are inherently more noisy, have worse CMRR, and have higher DC errors, than non-differential amplifiers.  "  
Are you talking about the difference configuration of an opamp being more noisy than the " noninverting" or "inverting amplifier " configuration ?

Comment: If I use an instrumentation amplifier with a differential output, such as the ADA4255, will this be sufficient?

Comment: At the same time, LTC2057 has a very low offset voltage (Offset Voltage: 4μV (Maximum). However, LT1991 has 15-80 µV Vos. Doesn't the total Vos increase in this case?
Since there are signals varying by 30µV/C in the thermocuple, wouldn't this make a significant difference?